# How can I delete an item from a collection using a UUID?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple firestore collection, and I want to be able to delete an item using a UUID that is generated when an item is created. How can I do this?

My item looks like this

```
{ id: UUID,
  name: name,
  itemLocation: xyz,
  itemQuant: 1000
}
```

Comment: Is the 'id' field the same as the firebase key?

Comment: It is not. However, it seems better to use the firebase key. How can I access that data point?

Comment: There is a few ways, can you provide the function you are using to read the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Since there may be multiple documents that have the same value for the UUID field, you'll need to [run a query to find those documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query), and then loop over the results to [delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) each of them.

Something like:

```
db.collection("yourcollection").where("id", "==", "valueOfUUIDYouWantToDelete")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            doc.ref.delete()
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error querying documents to delete: ", error);
    });
```